# Are Java wait(), notify() 's implementation significantly different from locks?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, wait

Out of curiosity, when Java implements wait() and notify() methods, are they really just using locks? i.e., wait() acquires a mutex, notify() release a mutex, notifyAll() releases all mutexes (in the same object, of course)?

Other than being less cumbersome than using locks, are there other advantages of using wait() and notify()?

[EDIT] I realized what I confused myself about after Brian's comments:

wait doesn't lock, it releases the lock and passes it to someone else who's waiting on a synchronized statement for the mutex, then waits to be notified by someone else who has the lock and calls notify, which passes the lock back to the original thread that called wait. I think that's where you're getting confused. – Brian 17 mins ago

Comment: notifyAll() releases all waits on the same object. Not the same thing at all.

Comment: @EJP of course, i mean all waits on the same object, similar to releasing all mutexes that this objects acquire in the wait(), if their implicit implementations are the same.

Comment: how would waiting and mutexes be the same thing?

Comment: You are *assuming* that there *are* multiple mutexes, which is already different. You're assuming a difference and then asking if they're the same. Not a real question.

Comment: @EJP perhaps I didn't explain my question well. I made some edits. Can you look again?

Comment: your edited code would deadlock if you used locking.

Comment: `wait` doesn't lock, it *releases* the lock and passes it to someone else who's waiting on a `synchronized` statement for the mutex, then waits to be notified by someone else who has the lock and calls `notify`, which passes the lock back to the original thread that called `wait`. I think that's where you're getting confused.

Comment: @Brian - technically, there is no lock "passing" involved, just releasing and re-acquiring.

Comment: @jtahlborn It's passing in a rudimentary sense, just that the passing happens in an unfair way through release/acquire.

Comment: @CodeNoob I don't seen any difference. You're still make the same invalid assumption about multiple mutexes, and still asking a meaningless question. FYI it is more akin to semaphores than it is to locks.

Comment: @EJP yes, I realized what I confused myself about after Brian's comments.

Comment: @CodeNoob Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458384/is-condition-variable-used-to-perform-wait-notify)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wait()` and `notify()` don't do any monitor acquisition.  as the javadoc for these methods state, the caller must have acquired the monitor before calling.  in fact, `wait()` actually *releases* the monitor the caller acquired (although, i guess technically wait *does* do monitor (re)acquisition before finally returning).

Comment: How is the "monitor" different from a lock, then?

Comment: it's not really, it's just the terminology the javadoc uses.

Comment: There is quite some different between a monitor and a lock I guess. Monitor is a watcher checking if processes wanting to execute a monitored piece of code have acquired proper locks. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076971/java-concurrency/how-the-java-virtual-machine-performs-thread-synchronization.html

Comment: @3yakuya Not really... a monitor is the name Java uses for the low-level structure provided by the OS which maintains the state of a mutex lock. The structure is separate from the Java object, and gets allocated lazily only for objects whose monitor is actually contended for by more than one thread. Monitor is not an active process.

Comment: When you say *actually releases the monitor*. What does your interpretation of monitor mean? `class ObjectMonitor` from `/src/share/vm/runtime/objectMonitor.hpp`?  -1 from me

Comment: @overexchange the comment above yours describes what a java "monitor" is.  please don't downvote an answer just because you don't understand it.

Answer (score 14):

The other questions have focused on what the language says that `wait` and `notify` are - but that doesn't seem to be what your question is about... you talk about mutexes, which is an implementation detail and therefore JVM specific.

So we need to pick a JVM - let's pick openjdk (source available [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/)). The bit of code that (ultimately) handles all this stuff is found at `hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp`.

This maintains two datastructures - a wait set and an entry set. Waiting threads are added to the wait set and parked whereas threads attempting to take the monitor are added to the entry set and then parked. On `notify` a thread is taken from the wait set and added to the entry set. When a thread releases the lock it unparks a thread from the entry set if there is one. Note that these sets are actually implemented as queues (linked lists) so are treated on a FIFO basis.

Therefore, in this particular case the implementation treats waiting on an object's monitor and attempting to take an object's monitor in a similar way.

But this is just one implementation of one JVM (although it's likely that others do something similar) - so we cannot rely on it. So I suppose the question is why do you want to know? If it's just curiosity then look through the openjdk code, it's fascinating. If you plan on using this information in your code... don't.

**UPDATE**

I realise that saying "park" doesn't tell us much. The code that parks a thread is platform specific (and is implemented in an object called `PlatformEvent`, which `ParkEvent` extends). In the version of openjdk that I'm looking at the park code for linux can be found at `hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp` and this calls `pthread_mutex_lock(_mutex)`... so in answer to your question **yes** calling wait *may* take a mutex *on my machine*. Note that there's lots of stuff that happens above this which might prevent us getting to this point.

Comment: Implementation in `objectMonitor.cpp` looks similar to the contract shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables_2) for `wait()`. Discussed further, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458384/is-condition-variable-used-to-perform-wait-notify)

Answer (score 1):

`wait` releases the lock you already have with the intention of re-obtaining it at some point in the future after someone else calls `notify`. This is in addition to the locking mechanisms provided by `synchronized`. Basically, you use `synchronized` to obtain a lock, then you use `wait`, `notify`, and `notifyAll` to control how those locks are released and re-locked.

Answer (score 1):

`wait()`, `notify()` always work along with Synchronization , so comparison can be between Locks and synchronization. There is big difference between Locks like RentrantLock, ReadWriteLock and Synchronization [block, methods].

1. Locks dont use synchronization internally while `wait()`, `notify()` will need synchronization.
2. You use Lock along with java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition, which efficiently enables conditional locking, this is quite tedious to implement with synchronization..
3. You dont have any tryLock option with synchronization , you either take lock or wait. But with Lock interface you have the choice.

Comment: What i meant was using java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition, which makes conditional lock implementation efficient and easier. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Conditions are equivalent to wait/notify, so i still don't understand 2.

Comment: @jtahlborn: Its the ease of implementation. So if want to call wait(), you have to be in synchronized block but i can call lock in one portion of code and await in another based on my logic. It helps me organize my code better and allows more granular implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> Out of curiosity, when Java implements wait() and notify() methods, are they really just using locks? 
>   i.e., wait() acquires a mutex, notify() release a mutex, notifyAll() releases all mutexes?

Sorry, but none of that quite right.  :)

- It is the `synchronized` keyword that obtains the `monitor`.  i.e. this is a form of locking.  NB: using `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` does something similar.
- `wait()` causes the current thread to wait until either another thread invokes the `notify()` method or the `notifyAll()` method for this object, or a specified amount of time has elapsed.  Nothing to do with locking - but can only call this method when the current thread current thread already own's this object's monitor (in a `synchronized` block/method)
- `notify()` wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor.  Again, nothing to do with locking - but can only call this method when the current thread current thread already own's this object's monitor (in a `synchronized` block/method)

Comment: I made a bit edits to my original question. Maybe that makes my quesstion clearer. Can you take a look? From your answer, if I understand correctly, there is no inherent difference between the implementation of locks and the implementation of wait(), notify()