# What happen after notify and before release for conditional locking

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, synchronization, locking

I see the following codes here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects

```
# Consume one item (thread 1)
cv.acquire()
while not an_item_is_available():
    cv.wait()
get_an_available_item()
cv.release()

# Produce one item (thread 2)
cv.acquire()
make_an_item_available()
cv.notify()
cv.release()
```

My question is, when `cv.notify()` is called in thread 2, thread 1 is waken from `cv.wait()`, but before thread 2 is calling `cv.release()`, thread 1 does not acquire the lock (am i right?)..My question is: what is the behaviour for thread 1 after calling `cv.notify()` and before calling `cv.release()` from thread 2?

**Update:**

I have found from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17337630/1497720, but its for java:

> This maintains two datastructures - a wait set and an entry set.
>   Waiting threads are added to the wait set and parked whereas threads
>   attempting to take the monitor are added to the entry set and then
>   parked. On notify a thread is taken from the wait set and added to the
>   entry set. When a thread releases the lock it unparks a thread from
>   the entry set if there is one. Note that these sets are actually
>   implemented as queues (linked lists) so are treated on a FIFO basis.

Answer (score 2):

the notify() and notifyAll() methods don’t release the lock; this means that the thread or threads awakened will not return from their wait() call immediately, but only when the thread that called notify() or notifyAll() finally relinquishes ownership of the lock.

Source: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#condition-objects

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of [`Condition.notify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Condition.notify):

> Note: an awakened thread does not actually return from its `wait()` call until it can reacquire the lock. Since `notify()` does not release the lock, its caller should.

So, the behavior after calling `cv.notify()` but before calling `cv.release()` is that thread 1 is still blocked at `cv.wait()`.